# jquery remove removing from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), jquery's remove function should work like so..

```
$('div').remove('selector');
```

Which I'm trying [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qwXSw/).

*HTML:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="unwanted">This should be removed</p>
    <p class="retained">This will remain</p>
</div>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div').remove('p.unwanted'); //not working
    //$('p.unwanted').remove(); //this works
});
```

​
It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the documentation is saying. It's not looking for elements that are descendants of the matched elements that match the selector, it's simply filtering down the set of already matched elements to those that match the selector, and then removing them.

If you have this HTML:

```
<div class="wanted">Some text</div>
<div class="wanted">Some more text</div>
<div class="unwanted">Some unwanted text</div>
```

and then executed this jQuery:

```
$('div').remove('.unwanted');
```

then it would only remove that third `<div>` (the one with the `unwanted` class on it), because it first selects *all* `<div>` elements, and then only removes those that match the selector.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kmww/)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to remove something that is both div and p.unwanted. The filter in remove() is applied to the current set of nodes, which in this case is all div elements.

Use the children set instead:

```
$('div').children().remove('p.unwanted');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
$('p').remove('.unwanted');
```

Argument in `remove` works as a filter. So here, you first select all `<p>` elements and then remove *only* those which have class `unwanted`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qwXSw/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, both you and Anthony answered at the same time. Shame I can't choose both.

Comment: @Finnnn Well... Actually, I have answered earlier at 57:47, while Anthony answered at 58:05. You can check if you hover the time. But I don't really care about it :) Good that you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').find('p.unwanted').attr('class', '');
});
```

Comment: That works but it doesn't do what the question asks. He wants to remove the element(s) entirely, not just remove all their classes.